# Trying to add variables to twitter json url

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I'm trying to create a function which uses a combination of jquery, json and javascript to retrieve a twitter feed using the $.getJSON() method.

I have the function working with a static url like so:

```
$.getJSON("http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/owzzz.json?count=1&callback=?", function(data) {
```

What I'm trying to do is replace where you see the username owzzz and count with values passed into the function.

the function looks something like this:

```
var twitterFeed = function(username, count){

$.getJSON("http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/owzzz.json?count=1&callback=?", function(data) {

    $.each(data, function(i) {
        var timestamp = new Date(this.created_at);
        var text = this.text;
        $("#twitter").html(text +'<a href="http://twitter.com/' + username + '/" class="timestamp">' + username + ' <span>' + timestamp.toDateString() + '<\/span><\/div>' ).click(function(e) {
            window.location = 'http://twitter.com/' + username;
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
}); } twitterFeed('owzzz',1);
```

I can add the passed value username in the .html() but not inside the getJSON();

Any idea how I would go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the same as you do in the `html` function: String concatenation.

```
$.getJSON("http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/" + username + ".json?count=" + count + "&callback=?", ...)
```

Comment: I did that originally but with single quotes instead of double and had no luck, it works perfectly now. Thank you :)

Comment: @Owzzz: You're welcome :) You always have to match quotes. If you start the string with a double quote, you have to end it with a double quote.

Answer (score 0):

string concatenation.

```
$.getJSON(
  'http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/' + username + '.json' + 
  '?count=' + count + '&callback=?'
);
```